# Aggregate SUM in a query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
select 
     ii.customer
     , CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,2),ISNULL((Select SUM(gld.amount) where inv.inventorydepartmentid='B00H'),0.00)) AS CD
     ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,2),ISNULL((Select SUM(gld.amount) where inv.inventorydepartmentid='A00G'),0.00)) AS Cam
from 
    invoiceitemview ii with (nolock)
inner join 
    master m with(nolock) on m.masterid=ii.masterid
inner join 
    warehouse w with (nolock) on w.warehouseid=ii.warehouseid
inner join 
    category c on c.categoryid=m.categoryid
inner join 
    gl on gl.invoiceitemid=ii.invoiceitemid
inner join 
    inventorydepartment inv on inv.inventorydepartmentid = c.inventorydepartmentid
inner join 
    gldetail gld on gld.warehouseid = w.warehouseid and gl.glid = gld.glid 
                 and m.masterid = gld.masterid
where 
    gl.gldate between @StartDate and @EndDate
    and ii.status IN ('CLOSED', 'PROCESSED')
    and w.warehouseid = '01'
    and w.inactive <> 'T'
    and ii.customerno = 'T1'
group by 
    ii.customer
```

However, this does not run because I have not included `inv.inventorydepartmentid` in group by clause. However, if I were to do that then it displays two lines of the same customer like the following:

```
Customer1     0.00   120.00
Customer1   500.00     0.00
```

Instead of

```
Customer1   500.00   120.00
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a sub-query?  Wrap everything in `SELECT * FROM (...) GROUP BY customer`  Just be sure to replace `*` with all the column names, and `SUM()` on any fields that should be added together.  This is after adding `inventorydepartmentid` to `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `select` syntax:

```
select ii.customer,
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,2),
               ISNULL(SUM(case when inv.inventorydepartmentid='B00H' then gld.amount end),
                      0.00
                     )
              ) AS CD,
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,2),
               ISNULL(SUM(case when inv.inventorydepartmentid='A00G' then gld.amount end),
                      0.00
                     )
              ) AS Cam
```

You are doing a conditional aggregation.  You don't need a nested `select`.  You only need to use the `case` statement correctly.

By the way, I've never seen a nested subquery with a `where` clause but no `from`.  A clever approach (even if it doesn't work in this case).  I hadn't realized that this was allowable syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try with a derived table. For instance, you are going to select the CustomerID, amount and then do your aggregations in a New SELECT statement. Also, do the grouping at the end of your select instead of writing it inside the derived table (or cte).
At the moment you are getting 2 results for each customer because you are grouping by BOTH customerID and departmentID which means every combination is being performed by the query ie it acts like a cross join, thats why you get the same customerID twice. Once you have customerID with departmentid= 'B00H' and then the same customerID with dedpartmentid= 'A00G'

```
with cte as (
select 
ii.customer
,gld.amount

from 
invoiceitemview ii with (nolock)
inner join master m with(nolock) on m.masterid=ii.masterid
inner join warehouse w with (nolock) on w.warehouseid=ii.warehouseid
inner join category c on c.categoryid=m.categoryid
inner join gl on gl.invoiceitemid=ii.invoiceitemid
inner join inventorydepartment inv on inv.inventorydepartmentid = c.inventorydepartmentid
inner join gldetail gld on gld.warehouseid=w.warehouseid and gl.glid=gld.glid and  m.masterid=gld.masterid
where 
gl.gldate between @StartDate and @EndDate
and ii.status IN ('CLOSED', 'PROCESSED')
and w.warehouseid='01'
and w.inactive<>'T'
and ii.customerno='T1'
)

select customer
,(select CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,2),ISNULL((Select SUM(gld.amount) from inventorydepartment inv (SOME KIND OF JOIN IS REQUIRED) where inv.inventorydepartmentid='B00H'),0.00))) AS CD
,(select CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,2),ISNULL((Select SUM(gld.amount) from inventorydepartment inv (SOME KIND OF JOIN IS REQUIRED) where inv.inventorydepartmentid='A00G'),0.00))) AS Cam
  from cte
  group by customer
```